# sentence complete, but how?

Tags: phrase-meaning

' I haven't been skiing - it's never really appealed. '

I suppose the sentence above is complete since it is from a well-known dictionary, however I cannot understand the second part of it, after the dash.

Comment: It's never really appealed **to me** is all I can imagine in a dictionary...

Answer (score 0):

**It's never really appealed** is another way of saying that **it has never attracted me** or **I have never been attracted to it**.

So the sentence is saying that the person concerned has never been skiing, mainly (or partly) because s/he has never found the prospect attractive or tempting. S/he has never desired to go skiing.

They are really two sentences (or related statements), separated by a dash instead of a semi-colon or full stop (period).

Comment: ' - it has never really appealed to me. '  Is it correct to write it this way?

Comment: @zigzag yes. Adding the "to me" would be 100% appropriate.

Comment: @zigzag Yes, it's quite correct, but optional. In context, **to me** is understood so it is not necessary to spell it out.